# Django login_required decorator does not work with ip 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, django

I have created a login system. The view is as follows:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            return redirect('home:index')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()

    return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{'form':form})
```

And I added a `login_required` decorator to the home page as follows:

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'home/index.html', context)
```

The problem is that when I access the index page with `localhost:8000/home/`, the page is redirected correctly to the login page. But with `127.0.0.1:8000/home/` the home page is rendered and I am not redirected to the login page!

Any solution?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you've previously logged in - by default a cookie will be set... try going to something like `/admin/logout` and that'll remove your django session (or clear our browser cookies)

Comment: Thanks dear that solved the problem!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably happen because you are already logged in in 127.0.0.1 domain
Try to clear your cookies or logout to solve that